# RadGridView for Winforms - foreign key column

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have the following columns in my bindingsource

```
    BookID, Name, Price, StatusID
```

`StatusID` is a foreign key.

Another table has the following columns

```
    StatusID, Status_Name.
```

I want `Radgridview` contains the following columns: `Name`, `Price`, `Status_Name`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query for reading those results, Like this:

```
SELECT
    a.Name, a.Price, b.Status_Name
FROM tableA a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableB b ON a.StatusID = b.StatusID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. Use hierarchical grid and you will have the first table on level 1 and the second table on level two. Here is an article how to set this up: [enter link description here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-hierarchical-grid-binding-to-hierarchical-data-automatically.html)
2. If you want the columns at one level, you will have to have them in a single table (see the answer from shA.t). Once you have them in a single table, simply bind the grid to it (set its DataSource property to the table instance)